# Flutter youtube_player_iframe not shown on mobile

Tags: flutter, youtube-api

I'm trying to show a youtube video inline in my Flutter app using the `youtube_player_iframe`.
The video is shown if:

- I launch the application on Android APK
- I launch the application from Android Studio emulator

However, a blank page is shown when:

- I open the web.app from ios mobile
- I open the web.app from an Android mobile
- I open the web.app from Chrome on my PC

Can anyone suggest which is the problem?

I tried to use also the `youtube_player_flutter` but in that case, the video doesn't start and is stuck at infinite looping when I open the web.app from ios/Android mobile and Chrome PC.

This is the code of the App:

```
class YoutubeAppDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YoutubeAppDemoState createState() => _YoutubeAppDemoState();
}

class _YoutubeAppDemoState extends State<YoutubeAppDemo> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        showControls: true,
        mute: true,
        showFullscreenButton: false,
        loop: false,
      ),
    );

    _controller.loadVideoById(
      videoId: 'egMWlD3fLJ8',
      startSeconds: 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*return YoutubePlayerScaffold(
      controller: _controller,
      builder: (context, player) {*/
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Youtube Player IFrame Demo'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
            YoutubePlayer(controller: _controller),
            const Controls(),
            ],
          )
        );
     // },
    //);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

///
class Controls extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  const Controls();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("MetaDataSection"),
          _space,
          Text("SourceInputSection"),
          _space,
          Text("PlayPauseButtonBar"),
          _space,
          const Text("VideoPositionSeeker"),
          _space,
          Text("PlayerStateSection"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _space => const SizedBox(height: 10);
}
```

[screen on emulator or Android APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqrt9.png)
[screen on PC web app link or accessing the web.app from ios/Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZuRC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `super.initState();` at the end of your `initState()`.

Here is a code sample that worked for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: YoutubeAppDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class YoutubeAppDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const YoutubeAppDemo({super.key});

  @override
  YoutubeAppDemoState createState() => YoutubeAppDemoState();
}

class YoutubeAppDemoState extends State<YoutubeAppDemo> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        showControls: true,
        mute: true,
        showFullscreenButton: false,
        loop: false,
      ),
    );

    _controller.loadVideoById(
      videoId: 'egMWlD3fLJ8',
      startSeconds: 0,
    );
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*return YoutubePlayerScaffold(
      controller: _controller,
      builder: (context, player) {*/
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Youtube Player IFrame Demo'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            YoutubePlayer(controller: _controller),
            const Controls(),
          ],
        ));
    // },
    //);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

///
class Controls extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  const Controls({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text("MetaDataSection"),
          _space,
          const Text("SourceInputSection"),
          _space,
          const Text("PlayPauseButtonBar"),
          _space,
          const Text("VideoPositionSeeker"),
          _space,
          const Text("PlayerStateSection"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _space => const SizedBox(height: 10);
}
```

Comment: same behavior as in the question. I added the screenshots in the question to show which is the output. the problem still remains when I use the web.app

Comment: what do you mean by web.app?

Comment: The one that can be run from Chrome from the PC or the mobile browser (compiling for Chrome(web))

Comment: do you have any errors in console? On iOS/Android is working?